# Sending more than 24576 messages per minute using Postal

Tags: linux, smtp

I'm using Russell Coker's [postal](http://doc.coker.com.au/projects/postal/) software to stress-test our mail server.

But I can't squeeze more than 24576 messages per minute out of it!

This seems to be a limitation on postal's side as I can fire up another instance on another machine (or the same machine) and easily squeeze through another 24576.

```
[root@client test]# postal -m 32 -M 4 -t 256 -c 128 -r 0 10.0.0.232 user-list
time,messages,data(K),errors,connections,SSL connections
14:21,13736,254013,0,416,0
14:22,25176,465690,0,358,0
14:23,24576,454808,0,352,0
14:24,24576,451941,0,375,0
14:25,24576,453869,0,376,0
14:26,24576,455206,0,385,0
14:27,24576,452850,0,356,0
```

Any idea if there's something else I'm missing or if there's something else I can change? After source-diving, I observed the throttling code doesn't even run when the rate-limit is the default (0), so it's not that.

Comment: 24576 = 3*8192 or 24*1024. That seems fairly significant.

Comment: Yeah, it is a rather nice round number.

Comment: Have you tried running another benchmark? e.g. http://www.postfix.org/smtp-sink.1.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a python script that would spawn a number of postal processes and aggregate the results.

Sometimes it's not worth solving the actual problem, but putting in a sensible solution that works around it.

If anyone happens to need to solve this particular problem in the future, get in touch with me and I may be able to pass the code on to you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to give the user running postal more than 1024 file handles?